# Parse text and save in memory c#

Tags: c#, string

I have such text

```
 5     1     5     1     5      1     5      1       
       1
```

I must get

```
 5     1     5     1     5      1     5      1       
 0     1     0     0     0      0     0      0
```

and save it in memory. But when i use such consruction:

```
List<string> lines=File.ReadLines(fileName);
foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split( new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach(string w in words)
                Console.Write("{0,6}", w);

            // filling out
            for (int i = words.Length; i < 8; i++)
                Console.Write("{0,6}", "0.");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

I only print text in desired format on display.
How I can save it in `List<string> newLines`?

Comment: So you want to save your output as it is in list as string?

Comment: If you `RemoveEmptyEntries`, how could you ever know what position the  `1` on the second line is? Frankly for parsing that, I simply don't think `Split` is the right option

Comment: I'm not putting as answer as not sure if its what you want but instead (or as well as) `Console.Write`, you can use `newLines.Add(string)`

Comment: What is exactly stored in second line? Is there white spaces, tabs? Is there any text after character `1`? What is separator of columns?

Comment: Will the file will have only two lines always or this could vary ??

Comment: @Shaharyar,yes, you are right.

Comment: @yogi, file have more than two lines but each line contains only 8 values.

Comment: The data currently is not equally spaced - is it meant to be ?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, '\t' and spaces are separators between columns

Comment: @Marc Gravell, it was my fault, I corrected it

Comment: @MykhailoVashchuk: Do you get the expected answer with the above code? Coz in the second line "1" gets printed on first column

Comment: @jacob aloysious. yes, thank you

Comment: @MykhailoVashchuk still not equally spaced :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume the data is meant to be equally spaced (as suggested by your current `Write` etc, then I would process it as *characters*:

```
char[] chars = new char[49];
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    // copy in the data and pad with spaces
    line.CopyTo(0, chars, 0, Math.Min(line.Length,chars.Length));
    for (int i = line.Length; i < chars.Length; i++)
        chars[i] = ' ';
    // check every 6th character - if space replace with zero
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.Length; i += 6) if (chars[i] == ' ')
        chars[i] = '0';
    Console.WriteLine(chars);
}
```

Or if you really need it as lines, use (at the end of each loop iteration):

```
list.Add(new string(chars));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is exactly 5 space between numbers. So here is the code:

```
List<string> lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName).ToList();
List<string> output = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var words = 
        line.Split(new string[] { new string(' ', 5) },
                   StringSplitOptions.None).Select(input => input.Trim()).ToArray();

    Array.Resize(ref words, 8);

    words = words.Select(
                input => string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? "  " : input).ToArray();

    output.Add(string.Join(new string(' ', 5), words));
}

//output:
// 5     1     5     1     5      1     5      1       
// 0     1     0     0     0      0     0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for producing your desired result :

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");
            string s;
            string resultText = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string text = s;
                string[] splitedText = text.Split('\t');
                for (int i = 0; i < splitedText.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (splitedText[i] == "")
                    {
                        resultText += "0 \t";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultText += splitedText[i] + " \t";
                    }
                }
                resultText += "\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(resultText);
```

"test.txt" is the text file that contains your text and "resultText" variable contains the result that you want.